# Multiple folders on server, create zip file for each

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, zip

I have a large number of folders on a server that I need to zip.

1. Each folder will be zipped to a separate zip file. Zip file name = folder name.
2. After zip is created, delete folder.

Can I do a batch file for this and what would be the script.

Answer (score 1):

Install [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and use this

```
for /d %%a in (C:\yourfolder\*) do 7z a %%~na.7z %%a\
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 or 10, in `cmd.exe`, one can use this [command](https://superuser.com/a/94437/116475) from [eleven81](https://superuser.com/users/8544/eleven81):

```
for /D %d in (*.*) do 7z a -tzip "%d.7z" "%d"
```

It assumes:

1. `cmd.exe` is in the folder that contains all the folders on a server that one needs to zip.
2. 7z.exe is the OS path environment variable:

[image]

[image]