# Batch archive multiple folders with 7-zip to other directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, zip, 7-zip

In reference to [this wonderful work](https://superuser.com/a/300152/938697):

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto :eof
:loop
7z a -tzip "%~1.zip" "%~1"
shift
if not [%1]==[] goto loop
```

I can't for the heck of it figure out where to put the output directory. I want to batch archive from my external hard drives, most of which are completely filled up. So I need to change the output directory to another drive.

I managed to find a way to do it with the following command line:

```
for /d %X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "<destinationPath>\%X.zip" "%X\"
```

However the above batch file would really come in handy because I could simply drop as many folders onto it as I have spare storage space, then move the archives and proceed with the next batch.

On Windows here by the way so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `7z` command in the batch file you provided uses the full path of the input file to get the output file.

In order to change this, you can change `"%~1.zip"` to `"<destinationPath>\%~nx1.zip"` as shown below or to `"<destinationPath>\%~n1.zip"` if you don't need the extension of the original file to be in the new filename.

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto :eof
:loop
7z a -tzip "<destinationPath>\%~nx1.zip" "%~1"
shift
if not [%1]==[] goto loop
```

For clarification:

- `%~1` represents the fully qualified path name of the first input (ex: C:\my\path\text.txt)
- `%~n1` represents the filename only of the first input (ex: text)
- `%~x1` represents the extension only of the first input (ex: .txt)
- These two are combined into `%~nx1`, which represents the filename and extension of the first input (ex: test.txt)

Comment: Sensational! Where do you learn this stuff? I searched all over the place. Is there a definitive batch/cmd guide or something?

Comment: I've found [Rob Van Der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php) and [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) to be good references. Some of these commands are also in unintuitive places. The information in this answer is from the [`FOR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) command.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I have marked down these resources for future references.