# What are the correct tags to use in a .bat file for 7-zip to achieve the same settings as the GUI?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, zip, 7-zip

Source for current problem solving: [Sevenip.osdn.jp](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm#7Z) but I cant get anything except -t7z -mx9 -m0=LZMA2 -mmt=1 -md=1024m -v10m to work.

I've been adapting [Enteleform's code from this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/94421/how-to-make-7-zip-do-a-whole-bunch-of-folders/1160047#1160047) to a similar question posted 10 years ago. This code currently works, but I'd like some clarification and some tweaking to the code. The batch file will create archives by just dragging the selected files/folders into the batch. The adjustments I've made are specifically to address changing the code to suit 7z instead of zip, and the tags on the following line:

```
!sevenZip! A -T7Z -M0=LZMA2 -MX9 !archivePath! !sourcePath!
```

Ultimately I'd like to use the following settings from the GUI:

***Archive Format:** 7-zip becomes -t7z*

***Compression Level:** Ultra becomes -mx9*

***Compression Method:** LZMA2 becomes -m0=LZMA2*

***Dictionary Size:** 1024MB becomes -md=1024m*

***Word Size:** 273 becomes -mfb273*

**Solid Block size:** Solid

***Number Of CPU Threads:** 1 becomes -mmt=1*

***Split to Volumes:** 1024M becomes -v1024M*

Code:

```
@Echo OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion



Rem //  7-Zip Executable Path
Set sevenZip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"



Rem // START: NewLine Variable Hack
Set newLine=^


Rem // END: NewLine Variable Hack !! DO NOT DELETE 2 EMPTY LINES ABOVE !!



Rem //  Set ErrorLog Variables
Set errorCount=0
Set separator=--------------------------------------------------------
Set errorLog=!newLine!!newLine!!separator!!newLine!!newLine!
Set errorPrefix=ERROR @:
Set successMessage=All Files Were Successfully Archived



Rem //  Loop Through Each Argument
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (%*) do (

    Rem //  Use Current Argument To set File, Folder, & Archive Paths
    SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    Set filePath="%%~x"
    Set directoryFiles="%%~x\*"
    Set archivePath="%%~x.7z"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    Rem //  Source Is A Folder
    if exist !directoryFiles! (
            Set sourcePath=!directoryFiles!
    )

    Rem //  Source Is A File
    if not exist !directoryFiles! (
            Set sourcePath=!filePath!
    )

    Rem //  Print Separator To Divide 7-Zip Output
    echo !newLine!!newLine!!separator!!newLine!!newLine!

    Rem //  Add Files To Zip Archive
!sevenZip! a -aoa -t7z -mx9 -m0=LZMA2 -md=1024m -v10m !archivePath! !sourcePath!

    Rem //  Log Errors
    if ErrorLevel 1 (
        Set /A errorCount=errorCount+1
        Set errorLog=!errorLog!!newLine!!errorPrefix!!sourcePath!
    )
)



Rem //  Print ErrorLog
if !errorCount!==0 (
    Set errorLog=!errorLog!!newLine!!successMessage!
)
Echo !errorLog!!newLine!!newLine!!newLine!



Rem //  Keep Window Open To View ErrorLog
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The solid block size limit is `2^64 - 1` bytes, as stated in [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/feb72a3e/#2ac3) on 7-Zip's SourceForge.

| 2^64 - 1 | bytes |
| --- | --- |
| 18446744073709551615 | *bytes* <sup>**B**</sup> |
| 18014398509481983 | *kibibytes* <sup>**KiB**</sup> |
| 17592186044415 | *mebibytes* <sup>**MiB**</sup> |
| 17179869183 | *gibibytes* <sup>**GiB**</sup> |
| 16777215 | *tebibytes* <sup>**TiB**</sup> |
| 16384 | *pebibytes* <sup>**PiB**</sup> |

7-Zip doesn't have an abbreviation for pebibytes, so we set the limit to 16777215 tebibytes like so:

`-ms=16777215t`

This should be the equivalent of selecting `Solid` in the GUI. *

<sup>*I'm not 100% certain on this; the documentation leaves much to be desired sometimes.*</sup>

---