# 7-zip - mutiple folders in seperate archives

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, zip, 7-zip

I most likely found the answer to my question in this Thread:

[How to make 7-zip do a whole bunch of folders](https://superuser.com/questions/94421/how-to-make-7-zip-do-a-whole-bunch-of-folders)

The user @Enteleform posted an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1160047/214658) and a script in there to create a batch file to drag and drop some folders onto it and it starts creating archives for each folder/files.
It is working create but I want to change the output directory.
He wrote that can be done at "archivePath" but I don't get it working.

I add my output directory like so

```
Set archivePath="E:\test output dir\%%~x.zip"
```

But I only get errors:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive: 3 files, 1208464 bytes (1181 KiB)

Creating archive: E:\test output dir\E:\test main dir\Caroline.zip

Add new data to archive: 3 files, 1208464 bytes (1181 KiB)

Error: cannot open file E:\test output dir\E:\test main dir\Caroline.zip
Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch.

System ERROR:
Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch.
--------------------------------------------------------
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive: 31 files, 631241499 bytes (602 MiB)

Creating archive: E:\test output dir\E:\test main dir\pictures.zip

Add new data to archive: 31 files, 631241499 bytes (602 MiB)

Error: cannot open file E:\test output dir\E:\test main dir\pictures.zip
Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch.

System ERROR:
Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch.
--------------------------------------------------------
ERROR @:"E:\test main dir\Caroline\*"
ERROR @:"E:\test main dir\pictures\*"

Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

I get it partly working if I just add the output directory without the %%~x.zip, that way it uses the correct output but it creates a zip file without a name.

Does some one have an idea whats wrong?

Edit: here the original script from Enteleform

```
@Echo OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion



Rem //  7-Zip Executable Path
Set sevenZip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"



Rem // START: NewLine Variable Hack
Set newLine=^


Rem // END: NewLine Variable Hack !! DO NOT DELETE 2 EMPTY LINES ABOVE !!



Rem //  Set ErrorLog Variables
Set errorCount=0
Set separator=--------------------------------------------------------
Set errorLog=!newLine!!newLine!!separator!!newLine!!newLine!
Set errorPrefix=ERROR @:
Set successMessage=All Files Were Successfully Archived



Rem //  Loop Through Each Argument
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (%*) do (

    Rem //  Use Current Argument To set File, Folder, & Archive Paths
    SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    Set filePath="%%~x"
    Set directoryFiles="%%~x\*"
    Set archivePath="%%~x.zip"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    Rem //  Source Is A Folder
    if exist !directoryFiles! (
            Set sourcePath=!directoryFiles!
    )

    Rem //  Source Is A File
    if not exist !directoryFiles! (
            Set sourcePath=!filePath!
    )

    Rem //  Print Separator To Divide 7-Zip Output
    echo !newLine!!newLine!!separator!!newLine!!newLine!

    Rem //  Add Files To Zip Archive
    !sevenZip! A -TZIP !archivePath! !sourcePath!

    Rem //  Log Errors
    if ErrorLevel 1 (
        Set /A errorCount=errorCount+1
        Set errorLog=!errorLog!!newLine!!errorPrefix!!sourcePath!
    )
)



Rem //  Print ErrorLog
if !errorCount!==0 (
    Set errorLog=!errorLog!!newLine!!successMessage!
)
Echo !errorLog!!newLine!!newLine!!newLine!



Rem //  Keep Window Open To View ErrorLog
pause
```

---

I know it is off topic but some critic to the "reputation" system:
I wanted to comment in the old topic but due to the reputation system I have to create a new question instead of just commenting in the existing one...

You want that I look for existing similar questions before adding a new one but that doesn't make sense if I can't answer or comment in that existing question as a new user.

Comment: you need to show the full script oder des wird nix ;)

Comment: The full script is in the other question linked above, but I will add it to my question.

Comment: After looking inside, it seems to me that there is some important part to it missing, but since usually, we do not develop programs for users, you need at first to understand what the script is doing

`Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...] [@listfile]` is the command interpretor and its missing the archiv name its ending afaik

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't want to become a programmer just for that.
The original script works great and I can just use the script as it is and move the created archives by myself but it would be nice if the archives where directly created at the right place.
And since Enteleform wrote the output path can be changed I thought it could be easily modified.

Comment: There is also a much simpler script from the user "roryok" in the same thread but is has the same problem with modifying the output dir.

I also found a simple batch that creates a zip file for every dir next to it and there I was able to modify the output dir without any issues.

    for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\"

Comment: `for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\"`

This forum is not easy to use...
Why can I only edit a comment for 5 minutes?

Comment: What I myself would do? (nobody cares but I will share anyway).  I would create a temporary directory and use MKLINK (or other soft/hard/junctions) to link the things I wanted into it.  Recursively create my zip/7z.  Delete the folder.  Perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to do.