Batch how to compress an .zip folder without root folder while also being portable
I'm trying to compress multiple separate folders to .zip (whether it be 7zip or PowerShell or tar)
as well as being portable (as in the .bat can be anywhere)
yes I looked at other posts but none of them is the answer to what I'm trying to do (if it's even possible)
mainfolder is where the .bat is
before compression
mainfolder | folder1 | folder .txt .json .png
this is what I want after compression
mainfolder | folder1.zip | folder .txt .json .png
but what I get is
mainfolder | folder1.zip | folder1 | folder .txt .json .png
I don't what the folder1 in the .zip
so is it possible to zip it without that other folder?

I finally found the answer I needed https://superuser.com/a/1544168/1782376

This is the same for any zip tool, but let's say you're using Powershell, and your folder structure looks like: C:\Folder1\Folder2\myFolders\myFile.txt:
# this zip will have a top-level folder (folder2) like you've seen
Compress-Archive -Path "C:\folder1\folder2" -Destination "C:\zip\file.zip"

# add an asterisk to take everything inside the target folder but leave the folder itself out:
Compress-Archive -Path "C:\folder1\folder2\*" -Destination "C:\zip\file.zip"


As an example using tar.exe in batch script:
@Echo Off
set "fol=C:\Temp\folder1"     & rem folder to zipped 
set "zip=C:\Temp\folder1.zip" & rem location of zip
pushd "%fol%" 2>Nul&& (tar.exe -cf "%zip%" "*" >Nul& popd)


The zip file will no additional root folder1.
Replace set "fol=... and set "zip=... as you wish.
Batch script can be placed anywhere.
To check whether tar.exe exists or not: where.exe tar.exe
more options tar.exe --help

Alternative using 7z:
@Echo Off
set "fol=C:\Temp\folder1"     & rem folder to zipped 
set "zip=C:\Temp\folder1.zip" & rem location of zip
set "sev=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
"%sev%" a -tzip "%zip%" "%fol%\*"


a -tzip archive type (-t7z/-trar/...)


it works but I can't open it by clicking on it as it says invalid yet I can open it with 7zip

If 7z is installed, it is better to use it which has more complete features. Or If PowerShell script, use Compress-Archive like @Cpt.Whale answer.

I might rather use 7z but how can I zip multiple files while also keeping the names it will also be portable as in it will be anywhere and still work

What does as portable mean?

I mean like if someone else uses the .bat it can download files to that spot and not to a specific folder it just does everything right where it is like in download or the desktop
